# Define variable in while loop

Tags: python

I going through a python course and am stuck at trying to use a while loop properly in my code

My code is supposed to check a password if it has min length =6 and max length =14, it will also check if the password only has numbers or letters. If it has a combination of both its supposed to print "strong password" if it only has numbers or letters it will print "weak password".

```
MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6

MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 14


while password_length >= MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH or password_length <= MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:

password_length = len(password)

password = input("Enter your password: ")


if password.isalpha():

    print("Your password is weak!")

elif password.isnumeric():

    print("Your password is weak!")

else:

    print("Your password is strong!")


print("Number of characters used in password: ", password_length,"the min length expected is: ",MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH,
"the max length is: ", MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
```

When I run my code, it comes with error message: 'name password_length is not defined'. I am not sure what to do? Is my code even correct? Am I supposed to put the password_length outside the while loop?

Comment: The code block could use indentations. (*Hint hint: you're using password_length before you're defining it.)

Comment: Also suggest you read [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Answer (score 1):

You have, more or less, the right idea. It's just that you need to assign a value to `password_length` outside your loop.

Think about this: when your code is run, the interpreter hits the `while` loop and attempts to make a comparison involving `password_length`. However, at that point `password_length` doesn't exist yet, since the first time it gets a value is *inside* the loop.  Therefore, you should initialise it to a sensible value, such as 0, before entering the loop.

Two supplementary points:

1. You're calculating the password length of the *previous* password, so if you enter a too-short/long password and then an acceptable one, the length printed will be of the unacceptable one.
2. In general, prefer f-strings or `str.format` calls to string concatenation, so, for your `print`, this might be better:

```
print(f'Number of characters used in password: {password_length}; '
       'the min length expected is {MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH} and the '
       'max length expected is {MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH}.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Immediately before the while loop, initialize with something like "password_length = MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH" or else the while loop cannot start. The first line inside the while loop is "password_length = len(password)", which will set the value of password_length correctly, but the while loop needs something to start with so that you can reach that point.

Answer (score 1):

Conditions in the while loop are wrong. You may try:

```py
MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6

MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 14

password = input("Enter your password: ")
password_length = len(password)

while password_length < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH or password_length > MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
    print("Password length", password_length, "incorrect. Required between", MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH, "and", MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
    password = input("Enter your password again: ")
    password_length = len(password)

if password.isalpha() or password.isnumeric():
    print("Your password is weak!")
else:
    print("Your password is strong!")

print("Number of characters used in password:", password_length,". The min length expected is:",MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH, ". The max length is: ", MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `password` and `password_length` variables before they are defined.

Also you can use function and rewrite it more structured:

```
MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6
MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 14

def checkPass():
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    password_length = len(password)

    if password.isalpha():
        print("Your password is weak!")
    elif password.isnumeric():
        print("Your password is weak!")
    else:
        print("Your password is strong!")

    return password_length >= MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH or password_length <= MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH

while checkPass():
    continue

print("Number of characters used in password: ", password_length,"the min length expected is: ",MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH, "the max length is: ", MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
```

[Online demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ry3BCsB_N)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your calling **password** before the code knows what it is.

```
MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6

MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 14

# password must be defined before you use it. 
password = input("Enter your password: ")

while password_length >= MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH or password_length <= MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:

password_length = len(password)  

if password.isalpha(): 
    print("Your password is weak!")

elif password.isnumeric(): 
    print("Your password is weak!")

else: 
    print("Your password is strong!")   

print("Number of characters used in password: ", password_length,"the min length expected is: ",MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH,
"the max length is: ", MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version based on what I understood

```
MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6
MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 14
password = ""
atLeast1Apha = False
atLeast1Numeric = False

while True:
    password = input("Enter your password: ")   
    if len(password) > MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH or len(password) < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
        print("Password could be between %s and %s long" %(MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH, MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH))
        continue
    for char in password:
        if char.isalpha():
            atLeast1Apha = True
        if char.isdigit():    
            atLeast1Numeric = True
    break        

if atLeast1Apha and atLeast1Numeric:
    print("Your password is strong!")
else:
    print("Your password is weak!")
```